# Add PHP string to include(file.php)

Tags: php, string, include

I had the below code that I can't get to work to save my life!  What am I forgetting?

```
    include('$fs_url/gallery/mysql.php');
```

Comment: THis is a "real Question" and you 6 should unblock this post.  It was very rude to block it just cause you are not smart enough to understand it.  At least Misch could help me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `'` with `"`:

```
include("$fs_url/gallery/mysql.php");
```

`'$var'` is not evaluated, `"$var"` is

---

To make clear what happens:

```
$x = 123;
echo "$x " . '$x';
```

yields:

> 123 $x

Answer (score 0):

You may try `include("./" . $fs_url . "/gallery/mysql.php");`